# multiple $http requests are pending whilst another is running, how to make them run concurrently

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have tried googling my issue but to no avail.

I am making an http request which can take a while to return, whilst this http request is running I want to make additional http requests running on an interval to report back progress.

The issue i am experiencing is whilst the first request is processing, all the requests that are sent via the interval seem to be queued up until the processing request is finished.

Below is a snippet of code of how i am performing the http requests, any help will be appreciated Javascript/AngularJS is not my main language

```
       $scope.ProgressHttp = function(){
        let files = $scope.files;

        var uFiles = [];
        for(let i = 0; i < files.length; i++){
            uFiles.push({
                FileName: files[i].filename,
                FileToken: files[i].getToken,
            })
        }

        $http({
            url : '@Url.Action("ProgressReport")',
            method : 'GET',
            data : { files : uFiles },
            headers: afHeaders
        }).
         success((data) => {
             data = data.Data;
             if(data.Success){
                 data.Progress.forEach((p) =>{
                     $scope.files.forEach((f) =>{
                         if(f.getToken == p.Token)
                         {
                             f.setStatus(p.Status);
                             f.progress = p.Progress;
                             return;
                         }
                     })
                 });
             }
         })
         .error(function(response){
             toastr.error("Error occured getting progress");
         })
    }

    $scope.ReportProgress = function(files){
        progressIntervalHandle = $interval($scope.ProgressHttp,5000);
    }

   $scope.processUploadedFile = function(files,metadata){
        $scope.processing = true;

        var uFiles = [];
        for(let i = 0; i < files.length; i++){
            uFiles.push({
                FileName: files[i].filename,
                FileToken: files[i].getToken,
                FileSize: files[i].data.size,
                FileType: files[i].data.type
            });
        }

      
        $scope.ReportProgress($scope.files);

        $http({
            url : '@Url.Action("ProcessUploadedFile")',
            method : 'POST',
            data : { uploadedFiles : uFiles, metadata : metadata },
            headers: afHeaders
        })
            .success(function (data) {
                data = data.Data;
                if(data.Success)
                    toastr.success("File(s) uploaded", "Success");
                else
                    toastr.error("File(s) failed to upload", "Error");
                $scope.uploadResults = data.UploadFileResults;

                if(data.FailedZipFile && data.FailedZipFile.length > 0){
                    let totalFiles = data.FailedZipFile.length;
                    $scope.downloadFile(data.FailedZipFile[data.FailedZipFile.length - 1],data.FailedZipFile,totalFiles);
                }

                $scope.processing = false;
            })
        .error(function(response){
            toastr.error("Error occured");
            $scope.processing = false;
        });
    }
```

In the developer tools it looks like the following

[image: developer tools]

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question. Don't add tags.

Comment: Have you considered using a socket connexion? That seems better suitable to your case

Comment: Take a peek at https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q